# Taking information from a website using Eggplant

Tags: eggplant

I need to take the specific data found on this web page and put it into an xlsx file.

I have to do it with the help of Eggplant.

Can anyone help me how can I do this?
I am attaching the website address.
I need to insert into an excel file the 2 specific columns from this website. I have attached a screenshot of them.

website: https://www.boi.org.il/he/Markets/ExchangeRates/Pages/Default.aspx

The 2 columns on the website that I need to insert into an Excel file  https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Jrx.png

Answer (score 0):

Eggplant is the wrong tool for this job. Hopefully this post will give you enough understanding as to why so you can advocate adopting a built for purpose tool. If not I will provide you towards the best options available to you within eggplant.

Eggplant is primarily an image based automation tool. It wasn't designed for web scraping. Recently they have added webdriver functionality but the closed source nature of Eggplant and the unconventional syntax of SenseTalk mean that it lacks the community support, and transferable knowledge that you get from integrating with Selenium from mainstream languages like Python, C#, or JavaScript.

The primary interaction Eggplant has with the SUT is via image capture, text recognition, and emulating mouse and keyboard events. This is a very powerful method for automating systems that cannot be automated using more built-for-purpose tools. However it is likely to be disrupted by even minor changes in layout or theming. Similarly reading data from the SUT is effectively limited to capturing a screenshot and performing text recognition on it. While Eggplant has put a lot of work into their image base automation, and text recognition systems. Such systems are extremely vulnerable to disruption by non-functional changes to the UI.

Technically Eggplant has added a [webdriver](https://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-webdriver-commands-and-functions.htm). Under the hood this is a barebones SenseTalk interface for operating a [selenium webdriver](https://www.selenium.dev/). Selenium is the industry standard tool for browser based testing. Instead of using images for locating UI elements Selenium inspects the browser's internal representation of the webpage. This allows for more information about individual elements, the structural relationship between elements, and won't be disrupted by purely visual changes in the UI.

Eggplant's documentation is notoriously bad. Their webdriver documentation is just a technical reference, useful if you want to know exactly what arguments a particular command can take, but opaque if you aren't already familiar with how Selenium works. Unlike using Selenium in any popular language where there are thousands of guides, tutorials, and explainers, with Eggplant, their official documentation is all there is. Furthermore the backwards and unconventional syntax of SenseTalk means that transferring knowledge from a resource intended for another language has the extra cognitive load of translating from syntax that is relatively similar across languages to SenseTalk's idiosyncratic syntax.

Additionally the super small community of Eggplant developers, means that there isn't the rich ecosystem of enhancements, plugins, and frameworks to draw from. Eggplant provides a barebones webdriver, anything you need you will need to implement yourself.

A dedicated webscraping tool will faster than a webdriver and requires less overhead to get data off a website. Most languages have library support for getting data into a spreadsheet.

---

#### If you absolutely must use Eggplant

- Use a [webdriver](https://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-webdriver-commands-and-functions.htm) to navigate to the desired webpage
- Use [selectors](https://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-webdriver-finding-elements.htm) to identify your target columns
- Extract the values from every element within a target column
- Store the extracted data in an [Excel file](https://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-excel-file-interaction.htm)